# Fetch layouts based on selected language of a spinner - Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have `layouts` defined for multiple languages and multiple devices like below:

[image: layout directories]

**Problem :** But I need to select `layouts` based on the language selected from a `spinner`, not the device language.

Comment: It isn't possible to choose a resource folder programmatically (or at least, not recommended). See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8943749/1908134.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved my problem :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String languageToLoad = "ar"; // your language you can get this as an input or save it in a file ,or do as your requirement
        Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
        Locale.setDefault(locale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = locale;
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```